# How to clean version control $Id$ comment

Tags: php, svn, version-control, cvs

This might be a common question, but search engines are horrible at searching for non-alphanumeric characters.

I have a bunch of code which contains the standard version control $Id$ tag/comment. I need an easy way to remove (clean, strip), all of these tags from every file in a directory structure.

Specifically this is a PHP script (phpBB to be specific), and so looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
*
* @package acp
* @version $Id: acp_attachments.php 8479 2008-03-29 00:22:48Z naderman $
*
*/
?>
```

The line I want to change is this:

```
* @version $Id: acp_attachments.php 8479 2008-03-29 00:22:48Z naderman $
```

So the line becomes:

```
* @version $Id$
```

Keep in mind, I'm on Windows, so I can't use a Linux command for find/replace. But I do have the ability to run PHP to act on all my files.

Comment: There are a number of projects that allow you to use common Linux utilities (like grep and sed) on windows. Also, Power Shell is equally powerful.

Answer (score 2):

On windows you can use [`grepWin`](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/grepWin.html) using this regex:

**Search for:** `\$Id\: .+ \$$`

**Replace with:** `\$Id\$`

**NOTE:** first make a backup of all files before doing this

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Perl?  Here's my `cvs-clean` script that I use for this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    s/\$([A-Z][a-z]+):[^\$]*\$/\$$1:\$/g;
    print;
}
```

It filters stdin to stdout.  It's not *exactly* what you asked for; it changes `$Id: blah $` to `$Id:$`.  Delete the last `:` in the `s///` command to change that.

If you can't use Perl, translating this to PHP is left as an exercise.